# How to extract multiple documents in lucene(ver. 4.7) with search query handler

Tags: java, lucene

My question is related to lucene. I am trying to get some specific documents from the index.

For Example :

I am reading a .txt file and creating an index of it. My each line is a new document. Now what i am trying to achieve here is that I want to select only few documents but in a single search query.

e.g

Input :-

Input lines where each line is a new document.
This is line 1 with some custom data
This is line 2 with random data
This is line 3 with unwanted data
This is line 4
This is line 1 with some custom data
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
This is line 1  with some custom data
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4

Expected Output :-

This is line 1 with some custom data
This is line 4
This is line 1 with some custom data
This is line 4
This is line 1 with some custom data
This is line 4

But the output coming is like this : -

Found 6 hits.
1. This is line 1 with some custom data
2. This is line 1 with some custom data
3. This is line 1 with some custom data
4. This is line 4
5. This is line 4
6. This is line 4

Can anyone help me with the code snippet that how can I achieve the same in single search query. Or which Kind of query parser could be useful.

Appreciate your help .

Comment: Not really quite sure I understand what you need here, but have you taken a look at the [Standard query parser syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Overview)?  Seems more than adequate here; Something like `"This is line 1" "This is line 4"`

Comment: @femtoRgon - Thanks for the reply. What i am trying to achieve here is that I have a .txt file which contains few lines which i mentioned above. So I read the file through BufferedReader() and for each line i create an document. Now since I need to find 2 lines out of these lines so basically when I compose my query      String q = "This is line 1 AND  This is line 4";  this query will basically fetch documents which contains both the lines 1 and line 4 so result will be 0 hits. If I use OR then also either of the line will be printed. How can I compose my query string to get both the lines.

Comment: Some how I was thinking proximity searches would make sense like "This is line 1 This is line 4"~3. But some how that is also not fetching me any results I don't know if my syntax is wrong or proximity doesn't apply for this situation.

Comment: The query provided above would search with, what amounts to an implicit `OR`, and so would get any document matching either of the search phrases.  An or won't just get one or the other of them at random, it will get both.  Are you seeing problems with queries you are actually running?  Because neither of the two queries you listed in your comment look like they will behave the way you have stated.  Neither `This is line 1 AND This is line 4` nor `"This is line 1 AND This is line 4"` behave the way you've said you expect.

Comment: @femtoRgon I have again corrected my problem. The query which i am passing is String querystr = "(This AND is AND line AND 1 AND with AND some AND custom AND data) OR (This AND is AND line AND 4)";   I have pasted the output which i am getting. Can you further extend your help and let me know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results look correct.  Lucene doesn't respect the order in which documents are added,it orders results by relevance score.  "This is line 1 with some custom data" matches 8 terms in your query, while "This is line 4" has 4 matched terms, thus the former has a higher score.  There is more complexity to scoring, including some factors that would equalize these somewhat, but in this case I believe that is the dominant behavior.

You can sort your results by passing in a [`Sort`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html) to your search call.  `Sort.INDEXORDER` is easy and sorts by Doc ID, which would serve your purpose somewhat.

However, Doc IDs are not guaranteed to be in insert order.  The more correct way to do this would be to add a field to sort on, which indexes either the time or order in which documents are indexed, and create a `Sort` on that field.

Comment: Thanks femtoRgon for the solution it really helped me solve my problem. Pasting the implementation of Sort in-case it would be helpful for others.  
TopDocs docs = searcher.search(q, hitsPerPage, new Sort(new SortField("isbn", SortField.Type.STRING)));
ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.scoreDocs;